# CiviCRM Home Dashlets - making them wider, possibly span over right and left column

Tags: dashboard, dashlet

I have a dashlet report that has a good number of columns. Right now I can only place it in either the left or right dashboard column. That cuts of the report view and I have to expand it every time I want to see the entire thing. Is there a way to make it wider on the dashboard or perhaps have it span over the right and left column?

Answer (score 1):

You can make the dashlets wider on the dashboard.

It's hard to give exact instructions because I don't know what CMS you're using - it's a good idea to post your CMS and CiviCRM version with a question for this reason - but if you're using Drupal 7, I like the [Civi Bartik](https://www.drupal.org/project/civi_bartik) theme for my back end.  It makes a number of sections wider, including the dashlets.  Make sure that `civicrm_theme` is enabled, then go to the "Appearance" section of Drupal and set the CiviCRM back-end theme to Civi Bartik.

Comment: A good option here would be to provide a third region of the dashboard that is full width.